# Creating multiple windows

Tags: electron

I'm using Github Electron and Angular 1.x to build a desktop application. I need to first create a Login window and once login is successful, wanted to show/instantiate the main/actual application window.

How can we destroy current Electron window instance and create a new window instance from AngularJS JavaScript Controller ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first suggestion I would make would be to not have multiple windows but to instead have multiple routes. To do routes in angular 1.x checkout out the [angular-ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-router).

Using routes you would use the same window and change the state of the application running inside of that same window.

However you can also have multiple windows by simply creating multiple `BrowserWindow` objects or by calling `loadURL` on the same window multiple times.

You can communicate back to the main process when login is complete using the [ipc](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) module, to trigger the desired behavior.

```
// main.js (main process)
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')

app.on('activate', () => {
  var win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/login.html`)

  ipcMain.on('login-success', () => {
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  })

})
```

Then in your render process just send the `login-success` message back.

```
// login.js (render process)
var {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

ipcRenderer.send('login-success') // call this after the user logs in
```